# Bessel decay for nonhomogeneous PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde, bessel-functions, green-function

I'm interested in the following nonhomogeneous PDE
$$ (\Delta-k^{2})u=-g $$
on the upper-half plane with smooth and integrable Dirichlet boundary condition, where $g$ is a smooth positive function satisfying
$$ g=O\left(\frac{e^{-kr}}{\sqrt{r}}\right) \ \ \ \ r\to +\infty \ .$$
Can we conclude that $u$ has the same asymptotic behaviour?

I know the Green function $G(w,z)$ for the operator $\Delta-k^2$, that can be written in terms of the modified Bessel functions $K_{0}$ 
$$
G(z,w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(K_{0}(k|w-z|)-K_{0}(k|w-\bar{z}|)\right)$$
I would like to prove that the integral 
$$ I(z)=\int_{H^{2}}G(w,z)g(w)dw $$
decays like $e^{-kr}/\sqrt{r}$ for $r\to +\infty$. Do you have any idea on how to do this estimate, or do you see any reason why this shouldn't be true?

Comment: Suppose that $z$ lies on the imaginary axis. My main problem is estimating the integral $$\int_{B_{z}(|z|)} G(z,w)g(w)dw$$ where $B_{z}(|z|)$ denotes the ball centered at $z$ and radius $|z|$. Using the fact that $\Delta G(z,w)=k^{2}G(z,w)-\delta_{w}$, do you think an integration by parts would work?